# Angular not detecting directives when creating components with createComponent

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have a structural directive that creates component by a given state.
The component that loaded via the structural directive is using *ngFor,
the problem is that the content in the *ngFor is not loaded and also the IDE tells me that "No directive is matched on attribute ngFor".
even though the directive and the component is declared in a module.

note: for testing purposes I tried to use *ngIf structural directive and it seems that it does work.
so it seems that problem is not that angular doesnt detect the *ngFor directive.

Here is the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wanzyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpage-1%2Fpage-1.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Floaders%2Floaders.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Floader.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Floaders%2Floaders.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpage-1%2Fpage-1%2Fpage-1.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpage-1%2Fpage-1%2Fpage-1.component.ts)

structural directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ifNotLoading]',
})
export class LoaderDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input('ifNotLoadingLoaderType') loaderType: TLoaderTypes;
    @Input('ifNotLoading') loading: boolean;
    private isInitialized = false;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (!this.isInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.handleCreateAndDestroyByLoadingState();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isInitialized = true;
        this.handleCreateAndDestroyByLoadingState();
    }

    private handleCreateAndDestroyByLoadingState() {
        this.vcRef.clear();

        if (this.loading) {
            this.vcRef.createComponent(LoadersComponent).instance.loaderToActivate = this.loaderType;
        } else {
            // embed the contents of the host template
            this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

component loaded via structural directive:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-loader',
    templateUrl: "./loaders.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./loaders.component.scss'],
})
export class LoadersComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('defaultLoader') defaultLoader: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('table') table: TemplateRef<any>;
    @Input('loaderToActivate') loaderToActivate: TLoaderTypes;

    constructor(
        private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
    ) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        switch (this.loaderToActivate) {
            case ELoaderTypes.table:
                this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.table);
                break;
            default:
                this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.defaultLoader);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

loaders.component.html:

```
<!--Table Loader-->
<ng-template #table>
    <table class="table-loader table-1 table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">XXX</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- table loader -->
        <ng-container>
            <tr *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" class="loading-reports">
                <td *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
                    <p class="animated-background row-data"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Please show `loaders.component.html`.

Comment: @N.F.
I added the html

Answer (score 0):

You need add your LoaderComponent to the shared.module.ts

```
import {LoadersComponent} from './loaders/loaders.component'
const EXPORTS = [LoaderDirective,LoadersComponent];
...
```

NOTE: The error Angular show really is a "bad friend", but rememeber, if we are using a component this component should be declared in any module

Comment: Hey Thank you for your response :)
this is the first thing that I tried to do and still doesnt work